# How to set a group environment variable in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

How do you manage group environment variables in gitlab ci? It looks like through the front end you may only add variables at project scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have GitLab 9.4+, you can set up [group-level environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#group-level-environment-variables) like this:

- Navigate to your Group
- Go to `Settings > CI/CD > Variables`.
- Group variables will be inherited by the group's projects and sub-groups.
- If you can't see the `Settings` or `CI/CD` menu options, you may not have sufficient permissions.

Side note: Environment-specific group variables are now available in *GitLab Premium*. See this [issue thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/2874).

Comment: To view these settings I needed to be the owner of the group and not just maintainer even though Gitlab docs doesnt explicitly mention it -https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#group-members-permissions

Comment: Looks like the docs do explicitly mention it now - there are separate entries for "Manage project-level CI/CD variables" and "Manage group level CI/CD variables".